# Ignoring some entities on flush in doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, entity

I have the following loop that [EDIT]does not work[/EDIT].

Background: I am importing a group of records in a symfony4/doctrine2 project. I want to avoid duplicate entries. As I parse records, if a duplicate is detected it is ignored, but if it's truly unique then it is persisted for later action by the flush() command.

What I find is that when I find a duplicate record, I cannot simply ignore it; instead I have to issue a `$em->clear()` command. Otherwise I get an integrity violation (I have a constraint on my entity to force unique the 'code' field to be unique on my entity).

ServiceCode entity:

```
class ServiceCode
{
    // omitting id and other properties

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $code;

    // omitting getters and setters
}
```

Loop to import new ServiceCodes:

```
foreach($records as $record) {
    $code = $record['code'];

    $newServiceCode = new ServiceCode();
    $newServiceCode->setCode($code);

    /** Avoid duplicate records **/
    $existingServiceCode = $em->getRepository(ServiceCode::class)
        ->findOneBy(['code' => $newServiceCode->getCode()]);

    if ($existingServiceCode) {
        $em->clear(); // this clears everything, so it's the wrong solution
        ++$duplicateCount;
    } else {
        // persist and save the new code
        $em->persist($newServiceCode);
        ++$importedCount;
    }
}
$em->flush();
```

My REVISED question: How to parse records and ignore duplicates, then import only new/unique records?

I have seen somewhat related questions, but these were related to entities pulled from the db where there is no need to persist because the entity arose from the db to start with. That is not the case here.

Comment: You shouldn't have to call anything inside that `if`. If you don't call `$em->persist($newServiceCode);` it won't be saved (and thus not raise an error), **unless** you have a relationship in another entity towards `ServiceCode`which cascades the persist operation!

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I had a property in a ManyToOne relationship that updated the inverse of that relationship. This led to the cascade that persisted everything in the background. Thanks for the help.